# How to display this useContext User in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use useContext in typescript. I am trying to use Usercontext in my child component.

Here is my `root app` component

```
export type UserC = {
  readonly user: string;
};

export const UserContext = createContext<UserC>({
  user: ''
})

<UserContext.Provider value={{user: 'kerry'}}>
//childs
//childs
</UserContext.Provider>
```

As you can see i am trying to export user from `root app`.
Inside my child component I am trying to user like this.

```
    <UserContext.Consumer>
        {
          user => {
            if(user !== null){
               console.log('not null')
            }else{
               console.log('null')}
            return ({user})
          }
        }
 </UserContext.Consumer>
```

But I am getting this error. What should i change in my code?

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {user}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you're referring to is the actual `context` object.
Try changing your code to:

```
    <UserContext.Consumer>
        {
          context => {
            if(context.user !== null){
               console.log('not null')
            }else{
               console.log('null')}
            return context.user
          }
        }
 </UserContext.Consumer>
```

Answer (score 1):

IT is because `<UserContextnConsumer>` should return JSX element instead of `{usesr}`.
You should end up with next code:

```js
 <UserContext.Consumer>
        {
          user => {
            if(user !== null){
               return <User user={user} />
            }else{
               console.log('null')}
            return null // Please keep in mind - null is valid React element
          }
        }
 </UserContext.Consumer>
```

Context.Consumer uses just `Child as Function` React pattern.
You can find description of pattern [here](https://medium.com/merrickchristensen/function-as-child-components-5f3920a9ace9) and more about Context [here](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

> This error is meaning that you render object,`{user}`.
> It mean you need to render `React Child(string, React Component, HTML Element...)`

### Answer

How about to fix code like

```js
 <UserContext.Consumer>
        {
          ({user}) => {
            if(user !== null){
               console.log('not null')
               return null;         // You need to return React child here
            }else{
               console.log('null')}
               return null;        // You need to return React child here
          }
        }
 </UserContext.Consumer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UserContextnConsumer** that you are utilizing, is based on a well-known pattern, called [renderProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), what is abstracted away from you is the fact that the consumer aims to render your children.

Currently you're giving the container component an object to render, which results in the given error.

Try something like this:

```
  <UserContext.Consumer>
        {
          ({user})=> {
            if(user !== null){
               console.log('not null')
            }else{
               console.log('null')}
            return (<>{user}</>)
          }
        }
 </UserContext.Consumer>
```